# Input type number onchange triggering late

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple *input tag* with *number type* with an `onchange` attribute:

```
<input type="number" onchange="someFunction()" />
```

My problem is `someFunction` is called when user clicks out of the input box. Why `someFunction` is not called while typing?
Also when user clicks on input type arrows to change value of the input, the first click triggers `onchange` event and calls `someFunction` but the second and third and other clicks wont call the function.
What can I do to call `someFunction` while user is typing (on fly) or user is clicking on the arrows of input?

Comment: Try googling the same question

Comment: I guess `onkeyup`.

Comment: The event is fired exactly when it is supposed to be fired, i.e. when the input losts the focus. If you need a realtime handling, use `oninput` event instead.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p04umf5L/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some other javascript events you should read about them. The event you want I think is `onkeyup`. A simple example here

```js
function someFunction() {
  alert("Hi there!");
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeyup="someFunction()"  oninput="someFunction()" />
```

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Comment: in this case the function is not called by clicking on input arrows

Comment: Try now @AliSeyfi

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using oninput event?

```
<input type="number" oninput="someFunction()">
```

Comment: oninput is not calling the function

Comment: It triggers when you input something in the input

Comment: Well, i've seen that the accepted answer has added my solution inside the tags

Answer (score 0):

`onchange` when fire the event after your input is blur

You are looking for `onkeypress`

```js
function someFunction(event){
    console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeyup="someFunction(event)" />
```

But I would rather recommend to add event listener rather than adding inline handlers. What I mean by that is

```js
document.getElementById("d").addEventListener("keyup", someFunction);
function someFunction(event){
    console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="d" />
```

Comment: in this case the function is not called by clicking on input arrows

Comment: and they are not considered as input keys

Comment: @AliSeyfi check now. You can use `keyup` event for that

Comment: its text input type. number input type is needed with its arrows

Comment: function would be the same. just change `type="text"` to `type="number"`

Comment: but problem is, clicking on arrows of input type wont call the function

Answer (score 0):

You must use `oninput` Event The oninput event occurs when an element gets user input. This event occurs when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed.
This event is similar to the `onchange` event. The difference is that the `oninput` event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while `onchange` occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed. The other difference is that the `onchange` event also works on `<select>` elements.

```
<input type="number" oninput="someFunction()">
```

Comment: I have tried oninput, but it does not triggers function at all

Comment: @AliSeyfi you must be doing something wrong then https://jsfiddle.net/p04umf5L/1/

Comment: Which browser have you tested? [check for browser support](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=oninput)